# What is the intersection of two balls in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: geometry

I know that the What is the intersection of two balls in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is either 0,1 or 2 points (since a ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is just a circle I can drew this).

What is the intersection of two balls in $\mathbb{R}^3$ ? is it at max 3 points ?

I would also like to know about the more general case of $n>1$

Can someone please help ?

Comment: Two spheres will intersect in a circle. Possibly with zero or imaginary radius.

Comment: A [ball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_%28mathematics%29) is often taken to mean the interior of a sphere, perhaps including the edge, which would make their intersections a lens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it will be a circle or a point (or empty), see this [wikimedia image](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sphere-intersect.svg):

[image]

Comment: It is also possible for the two spheres to not intersect, if e.g. the spheres are concentric or very far apart.

Comment: Of course, I added that part.

Comment: Thank you both, the picture really help me see that!